# Open a .exe file in %appdata% in console of C#

Tags: file-io, console, appdata

I Wrote this code to Open an .exe file in %appdata% in console:

```
try {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData  ));
}
catch { }
```

It opens appdata Directory but I want it to open an `.exe` file. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the exe name with the folder name before calling the program

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( System.IO.Path.Combine(  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData  ), "Exename.exe")
```